# How to display one of two texts but with the length of the longer one and show it on hover replacing the first one?

Tags: html, css

I have two texts with different lengths and I'd like to display only one of them (in this case 'come') but preserving as much space as the length of the longer one ('will come') so that I can switch them without changing the sentence width.

Is it possible only with css?

```
I promise I    come   to see you in the hospital.
I promise I will come to see you in the hospital.
```

Comment: You would probably need JavaScript to calculate the width of the longest string, then place the answers in a <span> or similar tag, and set the width to the longest string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with pure CSS.

You will want to wrap both potential options each in `<span>` element, and then both of those should in turn be wrapped in another `<span>`.

You can set each of the child span elements to be `display: block;` so that they sit on top of each other, and then you can show and hide one or the other by setting `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;`. This completely hides that one element, but allows it's width to still contribute to the size of the parent.. thus, the parent will be as large as the longest of the two options.

Then, the outer `<span>` just needs to be `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: bottom;` to stay in line with the text.

Add some extra styles for prettiness and to do the toggle on hover and you should have something like this:

### jsFiddle DEMO

Comment: This is exacly how I imagined I would be :-) I am not familiar with the overflow property yet so I'd better look for some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I made this in a few mins you can work off it and improve the basic functionality but here is the gist of what i did.

By using `span` and `visibility:hidden` rather than `display:none` it keeps its space even when its not actually visible.

Giving each `button`, `text input` and phrase an `id` that can use a key to identify it you'll be able to have multiple buttons, phrases and text boxes without needing to name every button, text box and phrase within your jquery.

here is the basic html

```
<p>A random phrase <span id="word1">to</span> test with</p>
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input type="button" id="btn1" key="1" value="test word"/>
<hr>
<p>Another random phrase <span id="word2">that</span> can be tested</p>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" key="2" value="test word"/>
<hr>
<p>Some random text <span id="word3">just</span> to create some test</p>
<input type="text" id="txt3"/>
<input type="button" id="btn3" key="3" value="test word"/>
<hr>
```

basic jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=button]").on("click", function(){
        var which = $(this).attr("key");
        var correctWord = $("#word" + which).text();
        var userWord = $("#txt" + which).val();

        if(correctWord == userWord){
            $("#word" + which).html(userWord).css({"visibility" : "visible", "color" : "#00cd00"});
            $("#txt" + which).css({"border" : "1px solid #00cd00", "outline" : "none"});
        }else{
            $("#txt" + which).css({"border" : "1px solid #ff0000", "outline" : "none"});
        }
    });
});
```

and the small bit of css

```
p span{
    visibility:hidden;
    color:black;
}
```

You will of course be able to see the correct spelling of the word within the source code but im assuming that wont be an issue with the way you asked the question.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/yuccaqh9/) showing it in action

Hope this gets you thinking on a way to carry on with your idea.

**EDIT** here is an updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/yuccaqh9/1/) which is more inline with what your thinking of i think.

You can grab the source code from there and play around with it.

Once again hope this helps.

Comment: You're right. I'm going to write the exercises myself (from a book) and repeat them a few times. I appriciate your answer unfortunately it does not meet the reqirements :-( replacing the text alone would not be a problem. In this case however I wanted to have the answer hidden "behind" the incorrect word but the whole space should take as much place as the longer text so that the rest of the sentence does not change if I hover over the incorrect word and swap the texts. I guess this explanation would have been better then my original question. If yes, then sorry for the unclarity.